Stuck at finding the syntax error in group_concat and prepare in MariaDB
This is a query to search all databases for a given string:
set @searchTerm = 'vidfactor.com';
set @likePattern = concat('%', @searchTerm, '%');

drop table if exists Modules.Queries;
drop table if exists Modules.SearchResults;
create table Modules.Queries
(
    Query varchar(400)
);
create table Modules.SearchResults (
    `Database` varchar(400),
    `Table` varchar(400),
    `Column` varchar(400),
    Value text
);

insert into Modules.Queries
select
    unique(concat(
        'insert into Modules.SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`)'
        ' select ''',
        ifnull(table_schema, 'Schema'),
        ''', ''',
        ifnull(table_name, 'Table'),
        ''', ''',
        ifnull(column_name, 'Column'),
        ''', `',
        ifnull(column_name, 'Value'),
        '` from `',
        ifnull(table_schema, 'Schema'),
        '`.`',
        ifnull(table_name, 'Table'),
        '` where `',
        ifnull(column_name, 'Column'),
        '` like ''',
        @likePattern,
        ''';'))
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('char', 'varchar', 'text', 'tinytext', 'mediumtext', 'longtext')
and table_name not like N'%Views'
and table_schema not in
(
    'sys',
    'information_schema',
    'mysql',
    'performance_schema'
);

select group_concat(Query separator '\n') into @finalSql
from Modules.Queries;

select @finalSql;

prepare query from @finalSql;
execute query;

select distinct `Database`, `Table`, `Column` from Modules.SearchResults;

deallocate prepare query;
-- drop table Modules.Queries;
-- drop table Modules.SearchResults;

When I copy/paste the @finalSql and execute it directly it works. However when I want to prepare it using prepare statement, I get this error:

Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'insert into Modules.SearchResults (Database, Table, Column, Value) se...' at line 2

I can't find the syntax problem. Any help is appreciated.
I'm using: MySQL version: 11.4.2-MariaDB-ubu2404 through PHP extension MySQLi

When I copy/paste the @finalSql and execute it directly it works. However when I want to prepare it using prepare statement, I get this error Show us the SQL text built in the variable.

@nbk This is not simple while browsing from the smartphone..

I can't find the syntax problem. The problem is simple - PREPARE statement does not support multi-statement query. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/ : "The text must represent a single SQL statement, not multiple statements". So the presence of the 2nd statement in your dynamic SQL causes an error. You must prepare and execute each statement separately.


I can't find the syntax problem.

The problem is simple - PREPARE statement does not support multi-statement query. So the presence of the 2nd statement in your SQL text which you want to be executed dynamically causes an error.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/

The text must represent a single SQL statement, not multiple statements.

You must prepare and execute each statement separately.


what should I do for performance? How can I create a multi-statement query and run them all at once? – Saeed Neamati

Your final SQL batch which you want to be executed as one solid multi-statement looks like:
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) select 'fiddle', 'Queries', 'Query', `Query` from `fiddle`.`Queries` where `Query` like '%vidfactor.com%';
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Database', `Database` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Database` like '%vidfactor.com%';
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Table', `Table` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Table` like '%vidfactor.com%';
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Column', `Column` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Column` like '%vidfactor.com%';
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Value', `Value` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Value` like '%vidfactor.com%';

So you may edit your code and make this insertion in single-statement form. This may look like:
insert into SearchResults (`Database`, `Table`, `Column`, `Value`) 
select 'fiddle', 'Queries', 'Query', `Query` from `fiddle`.`Queries` where `Query` like '%vidfactor.com%'
UNION ALL
select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Database', `Database` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Database` like '%vidfactor.com%'
UNION ALL
select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Table', `Table` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Table` like '%vidfactor.com%'
UNION ALL
select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Column', `Column` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Column` like '%vidfactor.com%'
UNION ALL
select 'fiddle', 'SearchResults', 'Value', `Value` from `fiddle`.`SearchResults` where `Value` like '%vidfactor.com%';

This query can be executed as dynamic SQL (via PREPARE).

thank you. So, what should I do for performance? How can I create a multi-statement query and run them all at once?

@SaeedNeamati Updated.
